# Find perpendicular from a point on a line

Tags: vectors, orthogonality

I need to find two points on opposite sides of a line in 2D at a distance $d$ from a point on the line.

If the line starts a point $A = (a, b)$ and ends at point $B = (c, d)$ in 2D (normal $x$-$y$-plane), then at a point $C$ located at a distance $t$ along the line from $B$ towards $A$.

I need to find the two points on the perpendicular through $C$ located a distance $s$ from $C$ on opposite sides of line $AB$.

What I have done so far (before my wheels came off) was to find point $C$ as follows:

calculate length = $\sqrt{(A-B) \cdot (A-B)}$

find unit-vector $u = (B-A)/\text{length}$

and so find $C = tu$, along $BA$

and then I got stuck. How do I find the perpendicular to $BA$ through $C$ and the two points at distance $s$ on that perpendicular?

Comment: if it has ends, it's a line *segment*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two dimensional space it is often useful to use complex numbers. Say $A=a+i\ b$, $B=c+i\ d$, and $C =\frac{t}{|A-B|}\cdot{A} +\left(1-\frac{t}{|A-B|}\right)\cdot{B}$

Your 2 points are $C\pm i\ \frac{s}{|A-B|}\cdot{\left(A-B\right)}$

I recommend reading about complex analysis, especially their polar representation, if You are not familiar with it.

Comment: I'm trying to code this in C++, but the complex-type in C++ does not allow for making an entire complex-number the imaginary portion of another complex number. Is there another way that the C+/- i part can be done that will allow handling the resulting real and imaginary parts separately?

Comment: @slashmais the idea to multiply by $\pm i$ is to rotate the vector $\pm \frac{\pi}{2}$. If this is not possible, how about rotating the vector $\pm \frac{\pi}{4}$ twice by multiplying by $\pm\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2}$

Comment: Ah! the pi/4 multiplying works a treat! thank you - wish I could up-vote you twice :)

Comment: ... and I also misunderstood that the `i` represents a multiplication and is not defining what follows it as imaginary. Changing my code to multiply with i also works. (it seems to be my slow day..)